# Prove that set {1, 0} exists.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have an exercise:

**Prove that set {1, 0} exists.**

Set theory is quite confusing for me to grasp at the moment but I know few axioms that should prove that this is set but how do I actually **show** this?
I know that:

- Axiom of pairing: For any a and b there exists a set {a,b} that contains exactly a and b.

- There exists an empty set ->   exists x forall y(!y in x).

How must I technically prove, using these axioms, that this specific set exists?

Comment: Use the axiom of pairing with $a=0$ and $b=1$?

Comment: Here $0$ and $1$ are notations for specific sets. Do you know which sets?

Answer (score 1):

Do you know how to construct the number $1$ and the number $0$?

Canonically, 
$$0 = \varnothing \\
1 = \{\varnothing\} \\
\ldots\ \\
n = \{ i : i \in [0, n - 1] \}
$$

Since you can construct $0$ with the rule you specified, and make $1$ by pairing $0$ with $0$, you can then pair $0$ and $1$ to get $\{0, 1\}$

Comment: The symbol for the empty set is $\varnothing$ or $\emptyset$ -- not $\Phi$, which is the Greek capital letter phi. (And you're missing set brackets in the last line of your formula -- $n$ is not the _union_ of all smaller numbers, but the _set containing_ each of them.)

Comment: $\bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1}i=n-1$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, drhab - thanks for the correction! I messed up the construction